# async / await and Task.Run -- How to know when everything is done

Tags: asynchronous, task, async-await

My actual program is more sophisticated than this, but I've tried to simplify things.

So let's say I'm reading a file with a list of URLs. I want to download the HTML from each URL and process it. The processing may be a bit complex, so I'd like it to be done on a separate thread.

The basic problem is how to tell when all the processing is done. For example, if the user tries to close the program before all URLs are processed, I want to give him a message and not exit the program. Alternatively, I want to terminate the program (perhaps with a MsgBox("Done") message) as soon as all the URLs are processed.

I'd like my code to look something as follows (assuming I've got an outer loop reading the URLs and calling this routine)...

```
List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();

async void ProcessSingleUrl(string url) {  
var web = new HttpClient();  
    var WebPageContents = await web.GetStringAsync(url);  
    Task t = Task.Run(() => ProcessWebPage(WebPageContents);  
    TaskList.Add(t);
}
```

The above code should run very quickly (Async methods run pretty well instantly) and return to the caller almost immediately.

But at that point, I may well have no entries whatsoever in TaskList, since a task isn't defined until the GetStringAsync is completed, and none (or maybe just a few) may have finished by then. So

```
Task.WaitAll(TaskList.ToArray());
```

doesn't work the way I need it to.

If absolutely necessary, I could first read in all the URLs and know how many Tasks to expect, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.

I suppose I could increment a counter just before the await, but that feels a bit kludgy.

I assume I'm structuring things incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to reorganize things.

Note: I'm not wedded to Task.Run. Good ol' QueueWorkItem is a possibility, but I think it has pretty well the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume I'm structuring things incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to reorganize things.

I think that is true. Here is a possible solution: Store the whole computation as a `Task` in your list, not just the second part:

```
async Task ProcessSingleUrlInner(string url) {  
    var web = new HttpClient();  
    var WebPageContents = await web.GetStringAsync(url);  
    Task t = Task.Run(() => ProcessWebPage(WebPageContents);  
    await t;
}

void ProcessSingleUrl(string url) {
var t = ProcessSingleUrlInner(url);
TaskList.Add(t);
}
```

Waiting on all tasks of this list will guarantee that everything is done. Probably, you need to adapt this idea to your exact needs.

Comment: It seems to me that this doesn't work. First, did you mean "return t;" instead of "await t;"? (An "await" with nothing after it doesn't do much, right?) And if so, aren't we back to where we started? Or am I missing something (again!)?

Comment: @LarrySmith If you left out the trailing await the task returned by `ProcessSingleUrlInner` would complete *before* `ProcessWebPage` completes. Awaiting it "includes" `ProcessWebPage` into the function. It ensures that `ProcessSingleUrlInner` does not complete before `ProcessWebPage` is complete. And that is the key to this solution: You get a task that only completes when *everything* is done. That is what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're getting the list of urls as an `IEnumerable<string>` or some such.

You can use LINQ to convert each url into a `Task`, and then `await` them all to complete:

```
async Task ProcessUrls(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
  var tasks = urls.Select(async url =>
  {
    var web = new HttpClient();  
    var WebPageContents = await web.GetStringAsync(url);  
    await Task.Run(() => ProcessWebPage(WebPageContents);
  });
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Note that if you use this solution and there are multiple different urls that have errors, then `Task.WhenAll` will only report one of those errors.